# Material UI Elevation Changes and Transitions

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm pretty new to `@material-ui/core`, but I have extensive experience with `@angular/material` and material design in general. Looking through the docs, the only place where I can find anything with regard to elevation is in the [Paper](https://material-ui.com/api/paper/#props) component, and superficially with the **`raised`** property of the [Card](https://material-ui.com/api/card/#props) component. Nothing is mentioned about elevation in the custom theming documentation.

In Angular Material, I am able to do the following in SCSS to get custom elevations with transitions:

```
.elevated {
  @include mat-elevation-transition;
  @include mat-elevation(2);

  &:hover {
    @include mat-elevation(6);    
  }
}
```

Is there a similar capability in Material UI?

[Angular Material Demo](https://angular-material-elevation-transitions.stackblitz.io/home) showing what I'm trying to accomplish.